# C# Class library Copy content not copied to output

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, class-library, nuspec

I made a class library in which i have a `.bin` folder containing files.
Two of these files (an exe and an extension-less file (node script)) have the folowing properties

```
Build Action : Content
Copy to Output Directory : Copy if newer
```

When I include my `.DLL`using NuGet in my project the `.bin` folder from the library gets copied to the web project's top level directory (reflecting where it is in the class library) but **not** to the output folder `bin` ...

Here is a part of my library's `.nuspec`.

```
<files>
    <file src="bin\Release\Wndrr.Mjml.CSharp.dll" target="lib\net45" />
    <file src="bin\Release\System.Management.Automation.dll" target="lib\net45" />
    <file src="bin\Release\.bin\mjmlFromString" target="lib\net45" />
    <file src="bin\Release\.bin\node.exe" target="lib\net45" />
</files>
```

Why, in the project that references my library via NuGet do I get the `.bin` folder dropped in my project top-level folder, where it's not needed at all and not in my output folder ? How do I get NuGet to copy these files to the `bin` instead of the top-level folder ?

Comment: Why the down vote ? If this question is bad, why are other people up voting ? Please explain your down vote so i can improve my question.